# Search every n characters in a string for a pattern

Tags: r, regex, string

Let's say I have the string `ABCC321BB321A`. I want to search for a pattern that consists of `ABC...321`, where `...` can be any character(s). However, I want to only return results in which characters in the substring can be grouped into sets of 3.

E.g., I don't want `ABCC321 (ABC - C32 - 1)`, but I do want `ABCC321BB321 (ABC - C32 - 1BB - 321)`.

How would I do this in `R`? Is it possible to achieve using regular expressions? I guess I could possibly split the string up into a list containing groups of 3 or use conditionals to only return matches that are divisible by 3 to get the answer I want, but I'm assuming there's a more efficient method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x <- "ABCC321BB321A"
threes <- regmatches(x, gregexpr(".{3}", x))[[1]]
threes
paste(threes, collapse = "-")
```

which produces:

```
[[1]]
[1] "ABC" "C32" "1BB" "321"
```

and

```
[1] "ABC-C32-1BB-321"
```